# Apache Camel content based router

Tags: xml, apache-camel, content-type, router

I made a `camel route` which contains an `xml` in an `activemq queue`.I want to route this `xml` according to a content property.How can i reach and make choice according to a property.I use `spring dsl`.My `xml` format like below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:imaOkuma xmlns:ns2="http://service.cxf.ws.sep.bedas.com/"><aboneDurum>0</aboneDurum>
<aboneNo>00006439705</aboneNo>
</ns2:imaOkuma>
```

I want to route this `xml` according to `aboneNo`.

Comment: In this example, where do you want to route the xml to (what is the route name?)

Comment: Yes,i mean if aboneNo is bla bla ,the xml goes to a queue else xml goes to another queue.@vikingsteve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using java dsl, where a simple choice would look something like this:

```
.choice()
    .when(xpath("/aboneNo")).isEqualTo("00006439705").to("activemq:queue1")
    .when(property("foo")).isEqualTo("bar").to("activemq:queue2")
    .otherwise().to("activemq:queue3")
.end();
```

Comment: I think i found the solution on [this](https://shahbazin.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/using-xpath-with-apache-camel/)